# How to change the background color of the DataGridView row and undo on hover?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I think this is a simple problem but the following code snippet not worked. If the current row is green I want it to be lighter green else I want light blue. When I MouseLeave, the colors must become the previous state.

In this code, whatever the color is, it becomes blue. When you move the mouse, it becomes white. It seems to be working fine in debug mode (entering if statement).

```cs
 private void dtgVeri_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;

        Color colorToChange=Color.LightBlue;
        Color colorCurrent = dtgVeri.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

        if (colorCurrent == Color.LightGreen)
            colorToChange = Color.PaleGreen;

        dtgVeri.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = colorToChange;
    }

    private void dtgVeri_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;

        Color colorToChange = Color.White;
        Color colorCurrent = dtgVeri.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

        if (colorCurrent == Color.PaleGreen)
            colorToChange = Color.LightGreen;

        dtgVeri.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = colorToChange;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried .Style instead of .DefaultCellStyle ? It seems that the .DefaultCellStyle has a cascade property so that may be why the entire table changes.

Comment: @S.Cassidy there is no **.Style** and don't think so I use in another code there was no problem.

Comment: My bad, that only applies to Cell objects, not Row. Anyway, glad you got it working.

Comment: could you clarify this one : **If currnet row is green I want it to be lighter green else I want light blue**  Let us know , what is  your  default row BackColor and SelectionBackColor ? According to your clause, you want backColor =  light blue, selection color = green and when mouse over selection it become lighter green. do I understand you correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem using `CellMouseEnter` event instead of `CellMouseMove`. Because `CellMouseMove` is constantly checking and creating problems but we want control only once hover at Enter and Leave.

Comment: i am trying to reproduce the situation . could you write, what color you used  for row (or cell)  and row selection background ?